# Is it possible to create polygon shaped elements in HTML?

Tags: html

I am currently attempting to make a `button` which is in the shape of a trapezoid.
I found a method of creating the shape which involved CSS making borders and such.
The CSS method worked in the way that it made the shape, but I ran into an issue where the whole element is contained in a rectangle, so when you click in the white spaces outside of the trapezoid it will still register as a click in the element.

In short, I am trying to make the HTML element to be the shape, of a trapezoid, not just the visible shape itself. Thus when a user clicks any area around the button that is outside the visible Trapezoid, but may be within the actual boundaries of a button rectangle, it should ignore the click. Thanks.

Edit:
It was asked that I show an example of what I mean.
http://jsfiddle.net/MichaelMitchell/aR72g/9/
In this link, there is the red trapezoid, but you can see the background color is also green, and when you were to click the green it still activates an `onclick`. In other word, I only want the red to be able to trigger the onclick.

Comment: Please provide the code that you are using. Also try to setup a http://jsfiddle.net of the issue.

Comment: Nope, not possible. Not unless you're using canvas or SVG for the whole thing.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have other clickable areas than rectangles in HTML if you are not willing to do the trickery involving `map` attribute and image ([see docs](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp)), but even then your image will always wrapped in rectangle bounding box (so you can only pretend to have different shape by using images with transparency and said `map`).

Comment: I was afraid I would have to do this. Is it required that you do it on an image, or can you do it on any other elements?

Answer (score 0):

You can work around this by giving it an onmousemove event that determines whether or not that coordinate is actually inside the trapezoid and adds/removes the onclick event accordingly. Something like this:

```
<figure id ="trapezoid" onmousemove="trapezoidMouseMove(event)">

<p>Button</p>
</figure>

<script>
function trapezoidClick(e)
{
    //Whatever you need it to do
    alert("inside");
}

    function trapezoidMouseMove(e)
    {
        //Fill in the angle of your trapezoid
        angle = Math.PI / 4;
        insideLeft = e.offsetX > Math.tan(angle) * e.offsetY;
        insideRight = e.offsetX < e.toElement.offsetWidth - Math.tan(angle) * e.offsetY;
        if (insideLeft && insideRight)
        {
            e.toElement.style.cursor = "pointer";
            e.toElement.onclick = trapezoidClick;
        }else{
            e.toElement.style.cursor = "default";
            e.toElement.onclick = null;
        }
    }
</script>
```